# Adding categorical variable based on the time in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database

```
CREATE TABLE data.atc full

    (
      index character varying,
      serial_nbr bigint,
      date_ date,
      time_ time without time zone,

    )
```

and the data looks like

```
"35107592";40873618845;"2016-01-20";"10:33:00"
"35107593";1600473508;"2016-01-20";"10:33:00"
"35107594";40872283641;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107596";713186627;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107598";42568856045;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107600";1836730779;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107601";713323741;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107603";713985185;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107604";40872125248;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107605";711995425;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107606";40877157402;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
"35107607";711492382;"2016-01-20";"10:34:00"
```

I wanna add another column to the database that takes value 0, 1, 2, ... for different time entries for a particular day and  a particular serial no. So, for every serial number, I can check out the first entry of the day and similarly second entry of the day and so on.

I start with adding column

```
ALTER TABLE data.atc ADD COLUMN od
```

I could not think any way to do this. Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to accomplish? There isn't a definite question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a query?

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by serial_nbr, date_ order by time_) as seqnum
from data.atc a;
```

You *can* store this value in the data, but then it is painful to keep it up-to-date.  The `update` takes place, new data comes in . . . and how do you assign the new values?

You can store the value using `update`:

```
update data.atc a
    set od = seqnum
    from (select a.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by serial_nbr, date_ order by time_) as seqnum
          from data.atc a
         ) aa
    where aa.serial_nbr = a.serial_nbr and aa.date_ = a.date_ and
          aa.time_ = a.time_;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I don't have to update the data. But how do I save seqnum into my database?